# MySQL Query too large? Results in unresponsive console

Tags: php, mysql, html

As I was trying to add a quote (via a PHP/HTML form) to my site that was particularly long, I noticed that the longer quotes did not get added via the MySQL query. The shorter ones got added just fine.

This is not a problem with the length of the columns in my table, the quotes are most definitely shorter than the limit (which is VARCHAR(600)).

When I try to manually enter the quotes into the database from the MySQL command line, hitting enter after entering the query properly does not result in a new prompt (it goes to the next line of the query instead). The query never executes.

The only way I can get to a new prompt is to force exit out of the MySQL command line and re-opening it. Anyone know why this is happening?

**EDIT**: Here is my query. The first 3 values are irrelevant, I won't confuse anyone by explaining them. The last 2 are the source and the quote.

**EDIT2**: MySQL version is 5.5.8

**THE QUERY THAT DOES NOT WORK**

```
INSERT INTO quotes VALUES(NULL, 2, 20, 'http://www.mlb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20091104&content_id=7620238&vkey=news_nyy&fext=.jsp&c_id=nyy', 'He's the reason we're here. First of all, we wouldn't be in this stadium if it wasn't for him. We wouldn't have this group together if it wasn't for him. It's a special moment. We all wanted to win it for him.');
```

**EXAMPLE OF A QUERY THAT WORKS**

```
INSERT INTO quotes VALUES(NULL, 2, 20, 'http://www.mlb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20091104&content_id=7620238&vkey=news_nyy&fext=.jsp&c_id=nyy', 'I guess you could say that this is the best moment of my life right now," Matsui said. "If I were to look back, yes, this would be the best.');
```

To those downvoting, mind telling me why?

**FINAL EDIT** Got it... it's because of the single quotes in my quote. Thank you.

Comment: make sure you are using *;* after finishing the query.

Comment: Could you post the query you're trying to run, including a quote that isn't working, for us to look at?

Comment: Also, can you maybe mention the MySQL version you have? MySQL up to and including version 4.2 only supported VARCHAR up to 255 characters, only MySQL 5 and up support longer VARCHAR's.

Comment: @neezer Query posted. @KilZone Version posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following things could cause the MySQL console to think that you have not yet finished your query, and there is more to enter:

- An unclosed quote, or backtick.

  - Usually due to the fact that you didn't escape a quote by doing `\'` (for single quotes) or `\"` (for double quotes).
- No semi-colon at the end of the query.

Make sure you don't have either of those problems and the query should run.

**Edit following poster's edit:**
Yeah, looking at your query, you need to escape quotes by replacing `'` with `\'` whenever it is inside an item of data. PHP has a function to escape for you which is `mysql_real_escape_string()`. You could also use prepared statements, which prevents this problem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) for more information.

Comment: look at my additional edits, I have a shorter query just like it that works. Additionally, I tried `\'` and it gives me an error: `Unknown command '\''.`

Comment: The fixed first query should look like this: `INSERT INTO quotes VALUES(NULL, 2, 20, 'http://www.mlb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20091104&content_id=7620238&vkey=news_nyy&fext=.jsp&c_id=nyy', 'He\'s the reason we\'re here. First of all, we wouldn\'t be in this stadium if it wasn\'t for him. We wouldn\'t have this group together if it wasn\'t for him. It\'s a special moment. We all wanted to win it for him.');` - is that what you have? Remember that you should only replace `'` with `\'` inside the data.

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely obvious, my friend ... you have single quotes in your last string, while using those as your string boundary ...

Comment: look at my edits and the query that works vs the one that doesnt

Answer (score 2):

When in the MySQL console, make sure you add a semicolon (;) to the end of the query.  Otherwise, it will expect more to the query.

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes.  So the quote in your non-working example would be: `'He\'s the reason we're here. First of all, we wouldn\'t be in this stadium if it wasn't for him. We wouldn\'t have this group together if it wasn\'t for him. It\'s a special moment. We all wanted to win it for him.'`

Answer (score 2):

You've got single quotes inside your string, which is encapsulated in single quotes.

You should be escaping your strings with `mysql_real_escape_string` (or something similar, like PDO): http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you did not escape the ' or " characters in the quote properly. look for any ' or " or \ characters and put a \ before them.

Answer (score 1):

You post no PHP code but your SQL suggests that you are omitting two basic steps:

1. Use prepared statements to inject data into your queries (or proper escaping functions)
2. Test the result of your DB calls and print/log error messages.